# date() function description in the PostgreSQL docs

Tags: postgresql, date

I am using the following code to extract the date part from any given timestamps in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DATE('2004-07-17 01:00:00');
```

The above statement works fine, and the result is `2004-07-17`.

However, where is the `date()` function described in the PostgreSQL docs?

I have searched for it extensively in this section: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html, however have found nothing of use so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's just syntactic sugar for standard SQL. In standard SQL, you express a date like this; PostgreSQL accepts the same syntax.

```
select date '2004-07-17 01:00:00'
```

Again, PostgreSQL returns the value '2004-07-17', and it's of type "date". I think the closest you'll find in the documentation is this paragraph in [Date/Time Input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT). (But this documents the SQL standard, not the syntactic sugar.)

> Remember that any date or time literal input needs to be enclosed in single quotes, like text strings. Refer to Section 4.1.2.7 for more information. SQL requires the following syntax
>
> type [ (p) ] 'value'
>
> where p is an optional precision specification giving the number of fractional digits in the seconds field. Precision can be specified for time, timestamp, and interval types.

Also, the syntax for timestamps is similar.

```
select timestamp '2004-07-17 01:00:00'
```

Note that this *won't* work in PostgreSQL . . .

```
select timestamp('2004-07-17 01:00:00')
```

but *this* will.

```
select "timestamp"('2004-07-17 01:00:00')
```

Comment: That's not the explanation because `date('somestring')` is not a cast, contrary to `date 'somestring'`.  If `typename('string')` was a cast to `typename`, then `int('1')` would work while in fact it produces a syntax error.Also `\df date` in psql reveals that there are 3 functions named `date` in `pg_catalog`.

Comment: *"If typename('string') was a cast to typename, then int('1') would work..."* I never said that "typename('string') was a cast to typename". I said that the SQL standards require date and timestamp input to respond appropriately to expressions like `date '2001-01-01 01:00')`. That includes returning a value of type "date". The SQL standards don't have a similar requirement for integers. The number of functions named "date()" don't eliminate the possibility of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' In postgresql manual it is clearly stated that `DATE('2004-07-17 01:00:00')` is a direct call to a function, that is used to cast strings to dates. It is not a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 4):

There is no description of `date()` function because it is just a `cast` of a sting to date. Like `cast('2004-07-17 01:00:00' as date)` or `'2004-07-17 01:00:00'::date`.

If I remember correctly, you can use the form `date('2004-07-17 01:00:00')` because internally all the casts are implemented as function and you are calling one of such functions directly. Or it can be just another piece of syntactic sugar.

UPDATE: The part of manual you are searching for is [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html). Chapter 4.2.9. Type Casts.

Also some useful information on how the casts are implemented [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html).

UPDATE 2: The quote from the manual:

> Note: The function-like syntax is in fact just a function call. When
>   one of the two standard cast syntaxes is used to do a run-time
>   conversion, it will internally invoke a registered function to perform
>   the conversion. By convention, these conversion functions have the
>   same name as their output type, and thus the "function-like syntax" is
>   nothing more than a direct invocation of the underlying conversion
>   function. Obviously, this is not something that a portable application
>   should rely on. For further details see CREATE CAST.